# how to render the result of reactiveValue correctly in shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny, and quite confused with the `reactiveValue`, expecially when it comes to `render` series function. Here is my toy example which just can't get the right value.

it gives the result of `argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`
even i try to `unlist` it, still get the error msg.

With my limited understanding, the `reactiveValue` is watching the environment, when something changed, it return all the information plus the variables listed, e.g, x & y.

I am trying to change the x and y value by the `actionButton`s, but just can't get the result properly.

Please advise and many thanks.

```
  library(shiny)
  rm(list = ls())

  ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("act1", "less x"),
    actionButton("act2", "more y"),
    textOutput("final")
  )

  server <- function(input, output, session) {
    value <- reactiveValues(x = 100, y = 0)

    observeEvent(input$act1, {
      value$x <- value$x - 10
    })

    observeEvent(input$act2, {
      value$y <- value$y +10
    })
    # i hope both value of x and y can be presented. 
    output$final <- renderText(value)
  }

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `output$final <- renderText(paste0('x: ', value$x, ' y: ', value$y))` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `reactiveValuestoList` function to convert your reactive object into a list, and then print it by using `renderPrint` instead of `renderText`.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    actionButton("act1", "less x"),
    actionButton("act2", "more y"),
    textOutput("final")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    value <- reactiveValues(x = 100, y = 0)

    observeEvent(input$act1, {
        value$x <- value$x - 10
    })

    observeEvent(input$act2, {
        value$y <- value$y +10
    })

    values <- reactive({
        reactiveValuesToList(value)
    })
    # i hope both value of x and y can be presented. 
    output$final <- renderPrint({
        values()
        })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

If you want a slightly nicer oututput, use the `paste` function to use renderText.

```
    output$final <- renderText({
        paste("X = ", values()$x,"Y = ", values()$y)
        })
```

Comment: many thanks, so I shall use another reactive function to watch the change of the previous reactive value. excellent!